# Saving Parsed JSON to MySQL with ActiveRecord in Sinatra

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I have a POST request to will take a JSON object. I believe I can get the variables out like this:

```
namespace '/api/v1/registrations' do
    post '' do
        request.body.rewind
        data = JSON.parse request.body.read

        type = data['type']
        value = data['value']
        id = data['unique device id']
        callcode = data['country calling code']

        "Type: #{type}, Value: #{value}, ID: #{id}, Calling Code: #{callcode}"

    end     
end
```

How would I then store each one in it's corresponding column in the table in my MySQL database using ActiveRecord?

Can I return JSON data in this same POST request? I'm pretty new to Sinatra and APIs in general.